# Icons in ArcToolbox window acting very strange?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox, icon

I am running ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop and for some reason my icons in the ArcToolbox and in other windows are behaving very very strange.  Sometimes no icon at all appears, other times the completely wrong icon appears. The icons will randomly change each time I load a new MXD.  I have searched the net for an answer but nothing comes up.  I attached a screenshot below.  First off anyone know why this is happening and if this is a serious problem that would require a re-install or other corrective measures?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any "weird" problem like this my troubleshooting sequence is something like:

1. Close and re-open ArcMap
2. If problem persists, close ArcMap, locate and rename/delete Normal.mxt, restart ArcMap
3. If problem persists, close ArcMap, uninstall and reinstall ArcGIS for Desktop

Comment: 1 and 2 didnt work :/  and I was really hoping not to have to do a reinstall but i guess I will