# Arctoolbox Icon Change to Folder Icons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, arctoolbox

As shown below my ArcToolbox icons have changed somehow, and I'd like to change them back.

[image: Icon]

Rebooting Arcmap helps but it will change back to folder icons after a while. How can I change them back?

I couldn't locate my Normal.mxt either. (ArcGIS 10.4)

Edit: apparently when I logged back in today, the error has ceased to appear so far. Restarting ArcGIS yesterday was no luck however. Not sure why, but will update if any issue arises.

Comment: Have you had other software installed lately?

Comment: Normal.mxt should be found in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.4\ArcMap\Templates`

Comment: No, not really. It's a work desktop. Normally nothing could be installed without admin password.

Comment: Access denied. Shall I delete the Normal mxt file to make it work?

Comment: Deleting Normal.mxt *might* make it work, or possibly ArcCatalog's Normal.gxt (in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.4\ArcCatalog`) but I couldn't say for sure as I've never seen this before

Comment: Similar Q&A here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175290/icons-in-arctoolbox-window-acting-very-strange - looks like the answer here may have been a reinstall of ArcGIS

Comment: Thanks, yeah I have seen that question. Hopefully it won't end up being that dramatic.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes get this problem, I find it happens after I have edited some metadata, this action seems to derail ArcMap, even in 10.5. I would just reboot ArcMap, not a lot you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks. Would you care to explain what metadata is in Arcmap?

Comment: @AndrewLebron ArcGIS has excellent documentation.  See [What is metadata?](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/metadata/what-is-metadata.htm)